# Entity framework Navigation Properties

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, navigation-properties

I am currently trying to develop my first .NET MVC application and so learning the main concepts.

In my application I have a table that displays a list of animals from an animals table. In the table I am also trying to display the animal breed, but I am pulling the breed from the Breed table on the foreign key stored in the Animal table[image]

I am currently trying to use a Navigation Property to display the Breed text and not the ID so I 
altered my Animal model to look like this

```
public partial class Animal
{
    public int AnimalId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> UserId { get; set; }
    public string TagNo { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Species { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> Sex { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> AnimalBreed { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> DOB { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> OwnershipStatus { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> DateAdded { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> BornOnFarm { get; set; }

    public virtual Breed Breed { get; set; }
}
```

And my breed model looks like

```
public partial class Breed
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> SpeciesID { get; set; }
    public string Breed1 { get; set; }
}
```

In my view I am trying to display the Breeds field from my animal model as shown below, but the breed column is just empty

```
<td>
  @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Breed.Breed1)
</td>
```

Also finally, here is the code that i am using to send the model to the view

```
List<Animal> Animal1 = (from animals in db.Animals
    where animals.Species == 2 && animals.OwnershipStatus == 1
    && animals.UserId == WebSecurity.CurrentUserId
    select animals).ToList();

return View(Animal1);
```

Answer (score 4):

First, don't pluralize single items. It creates confusion in your code:

```
public virtual Breed Breed { get; set; }
```

-or-

```
public virtual ICollection<Breed> Breeds { get; set; }
```

The `virtual` attribute allows lazy-loading (a query to fetch the breed will be issued the first time you try to access it). You pretty much always want to include `virtual` with the property so Entity Framework does not unnecessarily issue joins if you don't actually end up using the property. However, in this case, you *are*, so you'll want to tell EF to eager-load it by including `.Include("Breed")` in your query. However, that's just for optimization; it's not your problem here.

Your problem here is that Razor doesn't know how to display `Breed`. It's not a normal type, obviously, because you created it. So, what you really need is to display the actual property on `Breed` that you want:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Breed.Breed1)
```

There's an alternate method, but it's more complex and probably overkill for this scenario. If you really want to use `Breed` directly, then you need to define a display template for `Breed`. You do that by adding a new folder to `Views\Shared` named `DisplayTemplates`. Inside that folder, add a view named `Breed.cshtml`. The name of the view here corresponds to the *class* name, not the property name. Inside that view, you'd do something like:

```
@model Namespace.To.Breed
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Breed1)
```

Then, in your view you could just do:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Breed)
```

And Razor will use the display template to render the appropriate thing. Like I said, it's overkill for this, but in more complex object rendering, it might come in handy.

Comment: Hi Chris. Thanks for help, but I still havent solved the problem. I have altered my code and adjusted my question above to reflect it. I am still getting the same problem after taking your advice. It is still displaying a blank column. Am I doing anything wrong? Thanks

Comment: And you're sure that `Breed1` isn't actually blank? There's nothing making it required on your entity, so it could very easily be NULL or an empty string.

Comment: I just checked my Breed tablem and all columns in all rows contain data?

Answer (score 0):

If **lazy loading** is not enabled in your `DbContext`, then you have to explicitly load (or use eager loading) the navigation properties.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx

You'll end-up with something like:

```
var res = (from animals in db.Animals.Include("Breeds")
                                    where animals.Species == 2 & animals.OwnershipStatus == 1
                                    & animals.UserId == WebSecurity.CurrentUserId
                                    select animals).ToList();
```

Comment: Im still not sure how to "eager load" the query that I have above. I must incorporate "Include" into the select??